# Integral equation numerical solution with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

I'm trying to solve something like: `f[x] == Integrate[f[x]*g[x]]` where `g[x]` is known and `f[x]` is the function to solve (numerically is fine).

I've seen some examples of integral equations but wonder if there is a direct way to solve it with Mathematica.

Comment: `NDSolve[]` is meant for differential equations, and there isn't a built-in function (yet) for solving integral equations. OTOH, solutions to an inhomogeneous Fredholm equation of the second kind, like in your example, can be solved with the Liouville-Neumann series; such an expansion ought to be doable with the built-in functions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Would you care to comment about the field in which you've found this problem? (seems pretty difficult!)

Comment: Oh dear, your actual problem **looks nothing like** `f[x] == Integrate[f[x] g[x], x]` (thus, your "a bit more complex" is one hell of an understatement). This is a **nonlinear** problem, whose solution is much more difficult...

Comment: PCL, thanks for registering an account.  I merged it with the unregistered one so you should now be able to edit your own posts without the edit needing approval.

Comment: There are a few examples of numerically solving integral eqns in Mathematica.StackExchange.com and the older StackOverflow version. A search should locate them. That said, I do not know if any will help for your particular problem.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to solve the Fredholm equation of the second kind  which is an integral equation of the form

$$f(x) - \lambda\int_{a}^{b} K(x,y)f(y)dy = g(x), \quad \forall x \in [a, b]$$
you can use the following code. We follow the simplistic [source](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2008/WCE2008_pp933-937.pdf). One can make it much better by considering further implementation aspects as well as injecting more state of the art algorithmic antibiotic!!

### Code:

```
Options[FredholmKind2] = {Method -> Automatic};
FredholmKind2[{a_, b_, lambda_, k_, g_}, n_?IntegerQ,OptionsPattern[]] := 
Block[{step, SI, GI, KMatrix, W, DMatrix, f, deltaX, delta},
     step = (b - a)/n;
     SI = Range[a, b, step];
     GI = g /@ SI;
     KMatrix = Outer[k, SI, SI];
     W = {step/2}~Join~ConstantArray[step, n - 1]~Join~{step/2};
     DMatrix = DiagonalMatrix[W];
     f = If[OptionValue[Method] === NIntegrate,
            deltaX[x_?NumericQ] := W . (k[x, #] & /@ SI) - 
            NIntegrate[k[x, y], {y, a, b},AccuracyGoal -> 4];
            (*If the integral is expensive ParallelMap is an option here *)
            delta = deltaX /@ SI;
            Interpolation[
             Transpose@{SI, 
             LinearSolve[IdentityMatrix[n + 1] + lambda*(DiagonalMatrix[delta] -
                          KMatrix . DMatrix), GI]}]
             ,
            Interpolation[
             Transpose@{SI, 
             LinearSolve[IdentityMatrix[n + 1] - lambda*(KMatrix . DMatrix),GI]}]
          ];
      f
    ]
```

### Testing:

Now lets test it for the following equation which has an exact solution `Sin[x]`!! 
$$f(x) - \frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(x-y)f(y)dy = -\frac{2}{\pi}\cos(x), \quad \forall x \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$
There are two separate methods available called `Automatic` and `NIntegrate`. The second method is computationally more expensive but produces better result. The above function returns the solution `f` as an `InterpolatingFunction` which you can later use an ordinary function in MMA.

```
n=90;(*number of discretization*)
a = 0.;
b = 0.5*Pi;
lambda = 4./Pi;
Kpart[x_, y_] := Cos[x - y];
Gpart[x_] := -2. Cos[x]/Pi;
f1 = FredholmKind2[{a,b,lambda,Kpart, Gpart},n,Method -> Automatic];
f2 = FredholmKind2[{a,b,lambda,Kpart, Gpart},n,Method -> NIntegrate];
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
Plot[Evaluate@Sqrt@((Sin[x] - #)^2 & /@ {f1[x], f2[x]}), {x, a, b},Frame -> True,
Axes -> False,PlotLegend -> {"Automatic", "NIntegrate"},LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}]
```

[image]

In the above plot one can see how accurate the numerical solutions perform w.r.t the exact solution.

### To Do!

Now if you want to solve the Fredholm integral equation of the first kind which looks like

$$\int_{a}^{b} K(x,y) f(y) dy = g(x), \quad \forall x \in [a,b],$$

I suggest that you take look at [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=lvIDGgf5bCAC&pg=PA213) at page 213. After the above example it will be easy for you to implement the solution for the problem of first kind.

BR

Comment: Awake dead thread! @PlatoManiac, should you expect things to go badly for homogeneous equations (that is, with g(x) = 0)?

Comment: @plato Please take a look at this one http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58149/193

Comment: @belisarius Done! Thx for notifying though..:)

Comment: @PlatoManiac, I tried applying this solution for Kpart[x_, y_] := 
  Piecewise[{{1/Abs[x - y]^(8/3), Abs[x - y] >= u}, {0, 
     Abs[x - y] < u}}]; and Gpart[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{-1/2 + 1/2 (u/(1 - x))^(5/3), 
     x < u}, {-1/2 (u/x)^(5/3) + 1/2, 
     1 - x < u}, {-1/2 (u/x)^(5/3) + 
      1/2 (u/(1 - x))^(5/3), u <= x <= 
      1 - u}}]; for u <<1 and for a=0 and b=1. However, the solution doesn't satisfy the equation for x<u or x>1-u. I guess the problem is in the use of the Trapezoidal rule? Do you perhaps have a workaround for these kernel and source terms?

Comment: @PlatoManiac, thanks for this excellent answer. Have you considered solving for f(y)?

Answer (score 14):

I was not going to post this because in a previous edit (now gone) you showed a very difficult problem.

Anyway, the current question could be answered as follows:

You want to find `f[x]` satisfying

```
f[x] == Integrate[f[x] g[x], x]
```

for a known `g[x]`.

Differentiating:

```
f'[x] == g[x] f[x]
```

So for example

```
g[x_] := Sin@x^2;
fs = DSolve[f'[x] == g[x] f[x] && f[0] == 1, f, x]  
(*
 ->{{f -> Function[{x}, E^(x/2 - 1/4 Sin[2 x])]}}
*)
```

Testing it

```
Integrate[g[u] (f /. fs[[1]])[u], u]  
(*
-> E^(u/2 - 1/4 Sin[2 u])
*)
```

Comment: Sometimes, one is lucky, and integral equations (as well as integro-differential equations) can be reformulated as DEs. Still, one hopes that one does not have to resort to such trickery in future versions of *Mathematica*...

Comment: @J.M. `SolveForUniverseHamiltonian[ currentUniverse ]`