# Summa package problem

Tags: packages, expression-manipulation, summation

I need to use the features of the [Summa package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/3336/) but it doesn't work in *Mathematica* 9. It gives the error

```
Cannot open Utilities`FilterOptions`
```

My question is:

Is there an alternative (more modern) package with similar features, or a way to make `Summa.m` work in *Mathematica* 9?

---

Following @Nasser I solved it. The problem was that the input of [`FilterRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilterRules.html) is in opposite order, e.g.

```
FilterOptions[Expand,{opts}]
```

is changed to

```
Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts},Options@Expand]
```

Comment: oh, so the order needs to change also! good to know. I've updated Summa.m on my end, reloaded it, and now no error shows. Good to know it was this simple.

Answer (score 8):

As of version 9 this has changed  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compatibility/tutorial/Utilities/FilterOptions.html

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So this package needs to use `FilterRules`. I Downloaded this package, and changed `Summa.m` according to the above, and now it loads ok.

Changed every place it said `FilterOptions` to `Sequence@@FilterRules`. Run few tests from the notebook given. Example of change:

old:

```
inrule1[opts___Rule]:= c_ Summa[el1_,it:{k_,__}]:>
        Summa[If[$Explode,
                Expand[c el1,FilterOptions[Expand,{opts}]],
                c el1]  ,it] /; FreeQ[c,k];
```

new:

```
inrule1[opts___Rule]:= c_ Summa[el1_,it:{k_,__}]:>
        Summa[If[$Explode,
            Expand[c el1,Sequence@@FilterRules[{opts},Expand]],
                c el1]  ,it] /; FreeQ[c,k];
```

now

```
Get["Summa.m"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I put the updated `Summa.m` in this folder [here](http://12000.org/tmp/summa/) , replace your `Summa.m` with this version. If you find more issues with this, try to contact the author, they might have better solution or newer version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It is working now, except for the differential operator for sums, e.g. `s = x^2 Sum[Subscript[a, k] x^k, {k, 0, Infinity}];` `SumD[s, x]` gives an error. Do you happen to know what happened?

Comment: @Barefeg sorry, I do not use this package at all. I simply followed the instruction at WRI to upgrade it to V 9. I changed `FilterOptions` to `Sequence@@FilterRules` in all the places it was using `FilterOptions`. As I said, you might to contact the author on this to see why this error shows up. It might be an additional simple fix for option settings what is needed. But I do not really feel comfortable changing this package more. Do not want to break something. May be someone else will spot the problem with this use of Options.

Answer (score 2):

```
 If[Read[StringToStream[$Version], Number] >= 9  
   ,FilterOptions[a_,b___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[{b}, Options[a]]
   ];
```

would be a general use bridge to make notebooks and packages before version 9 and later compatible with respect to FilterOptions being superseded by FilterRules having a different call interface. You may place it into

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Kernel\Init.m    on Windows or probably
~/.Mathematica/Kernel/init.m                                   is the right place on Unix/Linux.
```