# Why this Solve cannot be solved

Tags: equation-solving, summation

```
Solve[Sum[p*a[i], {i, 1, n}] == 0, p, Reals]


Solve[p*Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n}] == 0, p, Reals]
```

The first line of code cannot be solved, but when the variable `p` is extracted and turned into the second line of code, it can be solved. What is the reason for this? How can the first line of code (i.e. using the original form) be made to run correctly?

Comment: What is the value of `n` for the first case? Put `n=4` and try again.

Comment: @Syed if put  a given number(such as n=4), the first code can solve.

Comment: As far as I know, currently none of those arithmetic related functions (`Solve`, `Simplify`, `Limit`, …) can handle unevaluated `Sum`. (Of course, there existed rather rare exception: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78777/1871 ) The best solution I can think out is to code a _shell_ as I've done here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71393/1871

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much,  I need to learn the solution  you mentioned.

Comment: Two other related posts: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96952/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129545/1871

Comment: @xzczd https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198186/94893  It seems that the problem has not been solved very well. I found that changing __Plus to __Times did not yield accurate results. Perhaps I cannot directly modify the code?

Comment: @xzczd now I try to learn use the first post in“ Sum not recognized as a linear operator by Solve ”

Comment: You don't need to modify anything. Just use the `expandSums`.

Comment: @xzczd the solution"expandSums" in "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198193/94893".   it is work for me ,very thanks!!!!!!!!!!!