# Converting a sum into Σ notation in output

Tags: summation

How can I convert the sum into  Σ notation in output? For example, I have an array of Array[k,4]. My input is

```
Array[k,4]
Sum[K[i], {i, 1, 4}]-K[4]
```

Then the output will be

```
K[1] + K[2] + K[3].
```

If I use Holdform in the input

```
HoldForm[Sum[K[i], {i, 1, 4}]-K[4]]
```

the result will be 
    $$
\sum _{i=1}^4 K[i]-K[4]
$$
What I want in the output is 
    $$
\sum _{i=1}^3 K[i]
$$

Comment: Would you kindly give additional examples?  This one seems too easy to be representative of your actual cases; I mean one would simply write out the result for something this simple.  Or are you handling many simple cases of the same form?

Comment: Have a look at my Summa package on Mathsource (or how they call it now). You only need to fix it according to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31426/summa-package-problem