# Fredholm integral equation of the second kind with kernel containing Bessel and Struve functions

Tags: special-functions, integral-equations

I need to solve this Fredholm integral equation of the second kind:

```
f[s]+integrate[f[t] K[s,t],{t,0,1}]=s
```

where `0<=s<=1`.

The kernel is:

```
K[s,t]=(a/2)*(BesselJ[1,a*(s+t)]-BesselJ[1,a*Abs[s-t]]-i*StruveH[1,a*(s+t)]+i*StruveH[1,a*Abs(s-t)])
```

where a: real, i: imaginary unit.

I tried to solve this with the method described here: [Integral equation numerical solution with NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11594/integral-equation-numerical-solution-with-ndsolve), this is the best algorithm for this case I have come across so far but it takes for ages and in the end it doesn't produce any result (due to memory insufficiency). Could anyone please help me solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There exist few typos in your kernel definition. This is how your kernel looks assuming `a=2` (we denote it as `A` while defining the kernel as `Kpart` in the following).
[image]

Please utilize the code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11594/integral-equation-numerical-solution-with-ndsolve) to solve your problem. Below I changed the constants and functional arguments of `FredholmKind2` to fit your particular problem.

```
n = 20;(*number of discretization*)
a = 0.;
b = 1.;
lambda = -1.;
Kpart[s_, t_] := With[{A =2},
(A/2)*(BesselJ[1, A*(s + t)] - BesselJ[1, A*Abs[s - t]]-I*StruveH[1, A*(s + t)]
+ I*StruveH[1, A*Abs[s - t]])];
Gpart[x_] := x;
f1 = FredholmKind2[{a, b, lambda, Kpart, Gpart}, n,Method -> Automatic];
f2 = FredholmKind2[{a, b, lambda, Kpart, Gpart}, n,Method -> NIntegrate];
```

In both the methods the `Re` and `Im` part of your complex solution function coincide pretty well.

```
(Plot[Evaluate@(# /@ {f1[x], f2[x]}), {x, a, b}, Frame -> True, 
Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Opacity@.45}, {Dashed, Red}},
 PlotLegends -> {"Automatic", "NIntegrate"}, 
ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {Re, Im})
```

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful (note:the Gpart is a function of s and equal to s not x). Is there a way to solve this without evaluating A? I am asking this because next I need to calculate the function 'K[A]=A^3 Integrate[s f[s],{s,0,1}]'.

Comment: @EvaPlevri I am afraid symbolic `A` will not fit here.

Comment: Do you know if there is another way to solve an integral equation with symbolic parameters in it?

Comment: Sorry! I do not know answer to your symbolic parameter question. I used `Plot3D[Kpart[s, t],{s,-1,1},{t,-1,1},PlotPoints-> 40]` to plot the kernel.