# Fredholm Integral Equation of the 2nd Kind with a Singular Difference Kernel

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations, singularity

After reviewing the literature, I could not find an analytic solution to the equation
$$\int^{1}_{0}dx\frac{f(x)}{|x-y|^{2/3}}=cf(y)$$
for $f(y)$, where $c$ is a constant and $y\in[0,1]$.

> I'm thus trying to find a numerical solution for it using Mathematica.

I've (unsuccessfully) tried using the approaches shown in "[iteratively solve integral equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152698/iteratively-solve-integral-equation)"
and
"[Fredholm integral equation of the second kind with kernel containing Bessel and Struve functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58149/fredholm-integral-equation-of-the-second-kind-with-kernel-containing-bessel-and)"
but was unable to apply the methods discussed there to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

This is an eigenvalue problem.

Let's apply a Galerkin scheme: We fix a finite dimensional space of functions, pick a basis $u_0, u_2,\dotsc,u_{n}$ and define the matrices

$$A_{ij} = \int_0^1 \!\!\!\!\int_0^1 u_i(x) \, k(x,y) \, u_j(y) \, \operatorname{d}\! x \, \operatorname{d}\! y$$
and
$$M_{ij} = \int_0^1 \!\!\!\!\int_0^1 u_i(x) \, u_j(y) \, \operatorname{d}\! x \, \operatorname{d}\! y,$$
where $k(x,y) = \frac{1}{|x-y|^{2/3}}$. Afterwards, we we solve the generalized eigensystem

$$ (A - \lambda) \, f = 0.$$

Depending on the basis you chose, you will get different methods. I guess trigonometric polynomials or Chebyshev polynomials should work fine with superior accuracy. I'll make it quick and dirty and use continuous piecewise-linear functions with respect to a grid $0 = t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n = 1$.

This is how we can assemble the matrices:

```
n = 1000;
xlist = Subdivide[0., 1., n];

M = SparseArray[{
    Band[{1, 1}] -> 2./(3. n),
    Band[{2, 1}] -> 1./(6. n),
    Band[{1, 2}] -> 1./(6. n)
    }, {n + 1, n + 1}, 0.];
M[[1, 1]] = 1./(3. n);
M[[n + 1, n + 1]] = 1./(3. n);

kernel = 1./(DistanceMatrix[xlist, xlist]^(2/3) + IdentityMatrix[n + 1, SparseArray]) 
  - IdentityMatrix[n + 1, SparseArray];
A = M.kernel.M;
```

We *could* use

```
{λ,U}=Eigensystem[{A,M}];
```

to solve the eigenvalue problem, but it takes rather long. Faster is this:

```
{λ, U} = Eigensystem[kernel.M];
```

A plot of the eigenfunctions for the eight highest eigenvalues can be obtained with

```
ListLinePlot[U[[1 ;; 8]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by [Henrik](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher), this is an eigenvalue problem. Since *Mathematica* doesn't have a built-in eigenvalue problem solver for integral equation, we need to discretize the equation to matrix form by ourselves and solve the resulting system with `Eigensystem`. Henrik has discretize the integral based on Galerkin scheme. Here I'd like to add a solution discretizing the integral with Gauss-Legendre quadrature formula:

```
eps = 10^-2;
points = 400;
integrand[x_] = (1/(eps + Abs[x - y]^(2/3))) f[x];
domain = {0, 1};
{nodes, weights} = Most[NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[points, MachinePrecision]];
midgrid = Rescale[nodes, {0, 1}, domain];
grid = Flatten[{domain[[1]], midgrid, domain[[-1]]}];
int = -Subtract @@ domain weights.Map[integrand, midgrid];
{b, m} = CoefficientArrays[int, f /@ grid];
mat = Table[m, {y, grid}];
{val, vec} = Eigensystem[mat, 8];
ListLinePlot[vec[[;; 8]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Error check:

```
With[{i = 1}, 
 With[{f = ListInterpolation[vec[[i]], domain], c = val[[i]]}, 
   ListLinePlot[
    Table[NIntegrate[f[x]/Abs[x - y]^(2/3), {x, 0, 1}, 
       Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}] - c f[y], {y, 0, 1, 1/100}], 
    PlotRange -> All]] // Quiet]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## Remark

1. Introduction for `` NIntegrate`GaussRuleData `` can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6966/1871).
2. The error of solution is relatively large, but it decreases as `points` increases.
3. The singularity is circumvented by adding a small value `eps` to the denominator of integrand, which is rough. I believe this is the root of inaccuracy of solution. Sadly I can't think out a better way to deal with the singularity.
4. Notice the definition of `mat` is somewhat opportunistic. It needs to be more sophisticated if the integrand involves `f[y]`.

Comment: I am a bit nervous because our results look so different... =/

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I think they're not that different, don't forget the eigenfunction can be scaled by any non-zero value :)