# Solving Fredholm equation of the 2nd kind

Tags: special-functions, integral-equations

While I was using the code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11594/integral-equation-numerical-solution-with-ndsolve) to solve this integral equation:

```
Al1[r] == SphericalBesselJ[l, k r] - (2 m I k)/\[HBar]^2 NIntegrate[If[r > R, SphericalBesselJ[l, k R] SphericalHankelH1[l, k r],SphericalBesselJ[l, k r] SphericalHankelH1[l, k R]] V[R] Al1[R] R^2, {R, a, b}]
```

where

```
V[r_] = -(1/r) - (1.0415223038416566` E^(-0.9990999998788636` r))/r;
```

and `l=0`,`m=1`,`k=Sqrt[2 e]`,`\[HBar]=1`,there's a severe problem.I put `Al1` from the output back into the original equation,check if the both side of the eqution were equal,and the result said otherwise.I don't know how this could happen.When I tried some other examples using the code,the results were just fine.Could anyone help me with this?

By the way,the integral limit should be from 0 to infinity,but since it's a numberical solution,I choose `a=1.*10^-5` and `b=50.`,but it shouldn't be a problem.The original equation is in Sakurai's "Modern Quantum Mechanics 2nd edition",p.444 problem 6.9 or problem 7.8 in some older version.

The complete code:

```
Options[FredholmKind2] = {Method -> Automatic};
FredholmKind2[{a_, b_, lambda_, k_, g_}, n_?IntegerQ,OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Block[{step, SI, GI, KMatrix, W, DMatrix, f, deltaX, delta}, 
    step = (b - a)/n;
    SI = Range[a, b, step];
    GI = g /@ SI;
    KMatrix = Outer[k, SI, SI];
    W = {step/2}~Join~ConstantArray[step, n - 1]~Join~{step/2};
    DMatrix = DiagonalMatrix[W];
    f = If[OptionValue[Method] === NIntegrate, 
       deltaX[x_?NumericQ] :=
        W.(k[x, #] & /@ SI) - NIntegrate[k[x, y], {y, a, b}, AccuracyGoal -> 4];
        (*If the integral is expensive ParallelMap is an option here*)delta = deltaX /@ SI;
    Interpolation[
      Transpose@
       {SI,LinearSolve[IdentityMatrix[n + 1] + 
          lambda*(DiagonalMatrix[delta] - KMatrix.DMatrix), GI]}], 
    Interpolation[
      Transpose@{SI,LinearSolve[IdentityMatrix[n + 1] - lambda*(KMatrix.DMatrix), 
         GI]}]];
    f]

(*some parameters*)
m = 1; \[HBar] = 1;
V[r_] = -(1/r) - (1.0415223038416566` E^(-0.9990999998788636` r))/r;
k = Sqrt[2 e]; l = 0;

(*solve the equation*)
n = 500; 
a = 1.*10^-5; 
b = 50.; 
\[Lambda] = -((2 m I k)/\[HBar]^2); 
Kpart[r_, R_] := 
 If[r > R, SphericalBesselJ[l, k R] SphericalHankelH1[l, k r], 
   SphericalBesselJ[l, k r] SphericalHankelH1[l, k R]] V[R] R^2;
Gpart[r_] := SphericalBesselJ[l, k r];
Al1 = Block[{e = 0.003}, 
       FredholmKind2[{a, b, \[Lambda], Kpart, Gpart}, n, Method -> NIntegrate]]

(*Test if the solution is correct at e=0.003*)
Block[{r = 0.01, e = 0.003},
 -Al1[r] + SphericalBesselJ[l, k r] -
  (2 m I k)/\[HBar]^2 
    NIntegrate[If[r > R, SphericalBesselJ[l, k R] SphericalHankelH1[l, k r], 
       SphericalBesselJ[l, k r] SphericalHankelH1[l, k R]] V[R] Al1[R] R^2, {R, a, b}]]
```

And the result of the last part of the code is `-0.00616647 + 0.0872912 I`.

---

The newest Mathematica 11 has ablilities to solve integral equation using `DSolveValue`. Not sure if numerical solution is possible that way.

Comment: Please provide the complete code sample to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry.I have posted the complete code above.

Comment: The definition of `\[Lambda]` is wrong, you missed a `I`.

Comment: Oh,bloody miss that.But the result is still not right.That `I` used to be there,I don't know when it's missing,but the result was never right.Now it's `-0.00616647 + 0.0872912 I`,the difference.

Comment: Probably because `n` is not big enough. `n=1000` produces `0.0010060712 - 0.0104718749 I`.

Comment: But shouldn't the error be at least less than `10^-6`?Or the accuracy of the final result(I use the Al1 in some other occations) would be huge,especially when the imaginary part's error is not small enough.And I tried to run it with `n=50000` once,it's just too slow,spent me hours to complete the calculation.

Comment: I don't think there's such guarantee… if you read the original paper, you will notice `FredholmKind2` is essentially discretize the integral with quadrature rule (some improvement is introduced when `Method -> NIntegrate` is added, of course) and the precision of the result will be undoubtedly influenced by `n`. BTW, `n = 50000` is way too large, `n = 2500` is probably enough, I guess. And you can try modifying the line `delta = deltaX /@ SI` to `delta = ParallelMap[deltaX, SI]`

Comment: Alright,I'll try it.Thanks a lot.

Comment: It may be better to remove the option `Method->NIntegrate`, without it the calculation is much faster and the error with `n=1000` is `-0.000224447 - 0.0137966 I`