# Attempt to code an Integro-Differential Equation Solver

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, special-functions, integral-equations

I'm interested in constructing a code that is able to numerically integrate a function at discrete points in order to implement into a numerical solver for a set of Integro-Differential Equation. In most of such cases, the right Reimann sum method (used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189778/using-dsolve-to-solve-an-integral-equation), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/ndsolve-integro-differential-equation/173001?noredirect=1#comment526833_173001) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204082/solving-ide-system-using-fdm-based-on-ndsolvefinitedifferencederivative)) seemed sufficient for the purpose.

However, the function I attempted to integrate has a singularity. It is defined as

$$\kappa(r,r')=\frac{2}{\pi}\begin{array}{ll} K(r/r')-E(r/r') & r<r' \\ K(r'/r)-E(r'/r) & r>r'\\ \end{array}$$

Where $K$ and $E$ are [complete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) respectively, $r$ is a fixed constant, and $r'$ is the integrand. Plotting this function, it is clear that $ \kappa(r,r') \rightarrow \infty$ as $r' \rightarrow r$.

[image]

While `NIntegrate` is able to integrate this function with complete ease, the Reimann sum integration code returns the error

```
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.
```

Why was `NIntegrate` able to integrate the function without encountering any singularity, and could we implement this feature into our Reimann sum integration code as well?

**CODE**

Definition of the function

```
unitStepExpand = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@# &;
    
x = 1; (*or any other arbitrary constant*)

\[kappa] = (
   2 r)/\[Pi] unitStepExpand@
    If[r > x, EllipticK[x/r] - EllipticE[x/r], 
     EllipticK[r/x] - EllipticE[r/x]];
```

The `NIntegrate` and Reimann sum integration are respectively done via

```
NIntegrate[\[Kappa], {r, 0, 1}]

int[expr_, {t_, L_, R_, step_}] := 
 step Total[Table[expr, {t, L + step, R, step}]]
int[\[Kappa], {r, 0, 1, 0.0001}]
```

**Additional Comments**

While `NIntegrate` on its own would work perfectly for the situation, the actual integral that I need to solve for is

$$\int_0^\infty \kappa(r,r') \frac{\partial c}{\partial r'} dr'$$

Where $c$ is an unknown that has to be solved through a series of differential equations, with which the integral is coupled. I would therefore be unable to directly use `NIntegrate` in the routine.

Comment: "Why was NIntegrate able to integrate the function without encountering any singularity" - because that's what it is designed for. It is capable of more sophisticated methods of integration, which is why I wouldn't implement my own integrating routine if I were you. Instead, I would try to advantage of the knowledge and expertise of the MMA programmers instead; after all, that's why I use MMA.

Comment: "Why was `NIntegrate` able to integrate the function without encountering any singularity" - that might be because the points where the function was evaluated luckily did not hit the integrable singularity.

Comment: @MarcoB I would like to use NIntegrate directly but the purpose of this implementation is to be able to work with discrete meshes, as I would be using it in an Integro-Differential Equation solver. To utilise NIntegrate directly would require me to interpolate through the meshes for every time step which is extremely time consuming.

Comment: This is insignificant, but in 2nd link I'm using Gaussian integral rather than Riemann sum. Then, the `Infinity::indet` isn't hard to avoid, just add a `If[…]` in the `Table` inside `int` to jump over the *bad* point, but this isn't the end, I think the real problem is, does naive integration methods (I mean those without any adaptive mesh or clever symbolic pre-processing) capable of handling this integrand involving singularity?